# selecting an item in a combobox pygtk glade3

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygtk, glade

Using pygtk 2.24 and glade 3 I'm having trouble with a combobox. When I click on an item in it I get the following error message

```
interface.py:94: Warning: unable to set property `text' of type `gchararray' from 
value of type `glong'
gtk.main()
```

My code for the combobox is here

```
#get the combo box out of the builder and add items to it
self.cbmoRepresentation = builder.get_object("cmbo_representation")
self.iface_list_store = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
self.iface_list_store.append(["Row-Column"])
self.iface_list_store.append(["Row-Number"])
self.iface_list_store.append(["Number-Column"])
self.cbmoRepresentation.set_model(self.iface_list_store)
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.cbmoRepresentation.pack_start(cell, True)
self.cbmoRepresentation.add_attribute(cell, "text", 0)
self.cbmoRepresentation.set_active(-1)
```

Any help would be really appreciated :).

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this that works (but I do not use glade) :

```
liststore = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
combobox = gtk.ComboBox(liststore)
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
combobox.pack_start(cell, True)
combobox.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
```

So I suspect your      self.cbmoRepresentation      not to be of the right type.
Please try :

```
  self.cbmoRepresentation = builder.get_object("cmbo_representation")
  print type(self.cbmoRepresentation)
```

to inspect the type of cbmoRepresentation.

Comment: <type 'gtk.ComboBox'>
Is the output.